# Erro ao renomear colunas em dataset usando o pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

Ao tenta renomear as colunas do dataset utilizando o pandas,eu estou tendo o seguinte erro

```
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

Abaixo o erro com a linha de código que estou utilizando:

```
File "<ipython-input-25-b3eccf173f1d>", line 1
    doencasCardiovasculares = doencasCardiovasculares.rename(columns={'age':'idade', 'anaemia':'anemia', 'creatinine_phosphokinase':'creatinofosfoquinase', 
'ejection_fraction':'fraçao de ejeção', 'high_blood_pressure':'hipertensão', 
'platelets':'plaquetas', 'serum_creatinine':'creatinina', 'serum sodium:sodio', 
'sex':'sexo', 'smoking':'fuma', 'time':'periodo de acompanhameno', 
'DEATH_EVENT':'morte durante o acompanhamento'}, inplace=True)
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

A qual atribuição exatamente o erro está acusando a qual eu estou me referindo?

Comment: O erro está aqui: `'serum sodium:sodio'`, deveria ser `'serum sodium': 'sodio'`. Uma vez que vc está atribuindo, também não precisa usar o `inplace`

Comment: Era isso mesmo,muito obrigado,nao tinha me atentado a esse erro

Comment: **Dica**: Sempre que o _error pointer_ (`^`) estiver apontando para o último caracter da linha, significa que é erro de sintaxe, normalmente carcter faltando, aspas no lugar errado, etc...